# Jquery make a div stop scroll on certain height

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html

Im trying to make it so that the servicewrapper div only scrolls to a certain height and stops there. And you cant scroll more on the page.

I started with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >=380) 
{ 
    $(window).scrollTop(380); 
}
});
```

It did the trick until i noticed that it stops all scrolling on all pages at the height.
So I tried wit this code so that the rule only applied to the servicewrapper div but with no luck. As you can see im no expert in jquery hehe.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if $('#servicewrapper').scrollTop() >=380) 
{ 
    $('#servicewrapper').scrollTop(380); 
}
});
```

Is there a way to do this? Been searching on google and on stack for a answear on this but I havent found any, at least not as how I want it to be and Im too much of a noob to alter someone elses code.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! It only worked in Firefox first but after a few tweaking it works on
IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome.
This is the code:

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
         $('#servicediv').css({position:'relative',top:200});
    } else {
         $('#servicediv').css({'top':30% });
        }
});
```

and the CSS:

```
#servicediv {
margin-top: 100px;
top:80%;
width: 100%;
background:url(images/content_bg.png);
height: auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 800;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 450px;

}
#servicewrapper {
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
height: auto;

}
```

Im answering my own question in case anyone else has this same problem and google this.
You have to tweak the rules to match yours ofc. 
And Im guessing a lot of you will go facepalm when you see the code. But its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control scrolling inside a container, you need to call `scrollTop` on that container. In this case, it looks like you're trying to affect scrolling down the whole page, so your container would be `window`. This part is correct.

If I understand you correctly, this script is being inserted into multiple pages in your site, and you only want to affect certain pages. If that's the case, you'll need to identify that page in some way. If only the target page(s) have an element called `servicewrapper`, then you can use that:

```
if($('#servicewrapper').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >=380) { 
            $(window).scrollTop(380); 
        }
    });
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MafPQ/

Comment: I copy pasted this code into my js file but it dosent do anything.
I have this:
if($('#servicewrapper').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >=380) { 
            $(window).scrollTop(380); 
        }
    });
}

And nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: It will need to be at the end of your HTML file, or else it will need to be wrapped in $(document).ready, like this: `$(document).ready(function() { /* CODE GOES HERE */ });`

Comment: now it looks like this: $(document).ready(function() {
if($('#servicewrapper').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >=380) { 
            $(window).scrollTop(380); 
        }
    });
}

});​

But it dosent seem to be working either. Im sure im copy pasting it totally wrong :P

Comment: The html markup is like this:
<div id="servicediv">
<div id="servicewrapper">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you beyond providing the code, since I don't know how your site works. But you should be able to see it working in the jsFiddle link. If you get it to run on your page, it should work. You could also try the `$('#servicewrapper').ready` method, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ssgSS/1/

Comment: Im thankfull for the help, but i cant get it to work. I copy paste your code and put in a js file with the document ready. How can i add it directly to the html ? Im using wordpress also.

Comment: I got this working:
$(window).scroll(function() {   
if($('#servicediv').length) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(window).stop().scrollTop() >=380) {
             $(window).stop().scrollTop(380);
            }
          });
}
});

But i need to set a timeout function, how do i do it?

Comment: You'll have to ask that in a separate question, it's much too big to answer in a comment. Please remember to accept this answer if it was helpful to you.